# Strange reaction in localhost with Next JS

Tags: html, next.js, localhost

I have a problem with the localhost of Nextjs and I can't find the cause.
The problem is the following:
the links of my pages display a 404 page, unless I remove its .html extension manually in the address bar.
But only in localhost. The pages work perfectly online.
HTML extension that Nextjs adds automatically.

If I change the next-config by adding the .html extension, it is the opposite. It works in localhost but not online.
If I remove the .html in the navigation menu, it works well in localhost, but does not find the pages online anymore...

Someone can help me please?

my next-js file :

```html
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
  exportPathMap: async function (
    defaultPathMap,
    { dev, dir, outDir, distDir, buildId }
  ) {
    return {

      '/fr/index': { page: '/fr' },

      '/': { page: '/' },
      '/en/the-school': { page: '/en/the-school' },
      '/en/admission': { page: '/en/admission' },
      '/en/events': { page: '/en/events' },
      '/en/school-life': { page: '/en/school-life' },
      '/en/partners': { page: '/en/partners' },
      '/en/contact': { page: '/en/contact' },

    }
  },
}
```

my nav menu :

```html
import React from 'react'

export default function NavMenu (props) {

    return (

    <header className="main-header">
        <div className="container">
            <div className="nav-content">
                <a href="/" className={props.logo}>Home</a>
                <nav className="main-nav">
                    <button className="toggle-menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="menu"><span
                            className="screen-reader-text">Menu</span></button>
                    <ul className="menu" id="menu" hidden>
                        <li className="menu-item"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                        <li className="menu-item"><a href="/en/the-school.html">The School</a></li>
                        <li className="menu-item"><a href="/en/admission.html">Admission</a></li>
                        <li className="menu-item"><a href="/en/partners.html">Partners</a></li>
                        <li className="menu-item"><a href="/en/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                        <li className="menu-item language"><a href="/fr/index.html">FR</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
  )
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Agreed with @mplungjan, you should post a Minimum code sample not as a screenshot  - In general when referencing internal nextjs links use the `<link>` component for standardized routing. Provide details around how you are deploying as well - is something else fronting the site

Comment: I think my issue is that now Nextjs automatically adds the .html extension on file.
But I can't get around it.

If I remove the .html from my internal links, I can navigate between the pages in localhost but it sends a 404 error in production.
If I add the .html of my internal links, it is the opposite, I have a 404 error in localhost but everything works in production...
I'm going to test the <Link> component of Nextjs, but I think my problem comes rather from the way I configured next.config.js.